# PHP mkdir pastas com o mesmo nome

Tags: php

Como fazer para quando se criar um diretório com mkdir ele não substituir caso haja um com o mesmo nome, manter as duas pastas com o mesmo nome ou com algum auto-incremento para numerar as pastas?

```
 $vregistro = utf8_decode($_POST['f_registro']);

 $d = date(' d-m-Y'); 
mkdir("C:\local\Arquivos\Documentos&Logos/$vregistro" . $d, 0777, true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assim como o Rafael citou em sua resposta, basta você sempre verificar a existência do diretório antes de criá-lo. Supondo a possibilidade de existir inúmeros diretórios com o mesmo nome, podemos criar um contator que será incrementado até localizar um valor válido no qual o diretório não existe.

```
$vregistro = utf8_decode($_POST['f_registro']);
$d = date(' d-m-Y'); 

$name = $vregistro . $d;

// Verifica se o diretório original existe:
if (file_exists($name)) {
    // Existe, então cria o contador:
    $i = 1;

    // Executa enquanto o diretório existir:
    while (file_exists(sprintf("%s (%03d)", $name, $i))) {
        $i++;
    }

    // Encontrou um diretório que não existe, então define o novo nome:
    $name = sprintf("%s (%03d)", $name, $i);
}

// Cria o diretório:
mkdir($name, 0777, true);
```

Assim, supondo que `$_POST["f_registro"]` seja `pasta`, o PHP irá verificar se existe o diretório `pasta 04-09-2017`. Se existir, irá verificar se `pasta 04-09-2017 (001)` existe, depois `pasta 04-09-2017 (002)`, `pasta 04-09-2017 (003)`, assim por diante, até encontrar um nome que não seja um diretório existente, criando-o.

> Perceba que ao invés de colocar o contador exibindo como 1, 2, 3, ..., coloquei exibindo como 001, 002, 003, etc; isso porquê se chegasse a criar o diretório 10, ou superior, a ordem dos diretórios seria afetada, pois o sistema operacional ordena de forma alfabética pelo nome, exibindo o 10 antes do 2, por exemplo. Adicionando os zeros à esquerda, isso não ocorrerá, exceto se a numeração ultrapassar 1000.

Comment: Isso ai, bem explicado :)

Answer (score 1):

Voce pode verificar se o diretorio ja existe, caso existir, voce coloco um adicional no novo nome.

```
if(file_exists($vregistro)){
   // Aqui voce cria pasta com o nome atual e algo a mais 
}else{
  // Aqui voce apenas cria com o nome atual
}
```

Comment: Mas e se for mais de duas pastas com o mesmo nome?

Comment: @HenriqueBretone voce adiciona algo a mais no nome da pasta, ex: pasta_1, pasta_2 e assim em diante